# Play sounds one after another with loop

Tags: javascript, loops, audio

I have four audios. Let’s say s1, s2, s3, and s4. I also have a variable with random integers between one and four, for example myVar = [2, 1, 3, 4]. It can be longer or shorter than four, but the integers in it will be always between one and four.

I want to make a cycle which will look on myVar and play my sounds in corresponding order (in this case: s2, s1, s3, s4). One sound after another, that is very important. Not all at once.

All my solutions play the sounds at once so far. I know there are several similar questions, but I am so bad at JavaScript that I was not able to use the answers. Anybody knows how to do it?

One of current solutions (does not work):

```
function recTime (i) {

  if (i === myVar.length) return;

  if (myVar[i] === 1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      s1.play();
      return recTime(++i);
    },350);}
  else if (myVar[i] === 2) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      s2.play();
      return recTime(++i);   
    },350);
  }
  else if (myVar[i] === 3) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      s3.play();
      return recTime(++i);
    },350);
  }
  else if (myVar[i] === 4) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      s4.play();
      return recTime(i++);
    },350);
  }  
  }

I call it in this cycle:

  for (var i = 0; i < stimuli.length+1; ++i){
  recTime(i);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I will put it under the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can also be a solution without mutation of 'order' array, for example using `Symbol.iterator` called for each `ended` event:

```js
var a1 = new Audio('http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg'); a1.id = "1"; // id helps to see console.log is fine
var a2 = new Audio('http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg'); a2.id = "2";
var a3 = new Audio('http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg'); a3.id = "3";
var a4 = new Audio('http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg'); a4.id = "4";

var order = [2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1];

rotateAudio(order); // main function; pass order array here

function rotateAudio(order) {
  var orderMap = {1: a1, 2: a2, 3: a3, 4: a4};
  var iterator = order[Symbol.iterator]();
  var value, done;
  
  function rotate({value, done}) { // get next iteration
    function next(e) {
      e.target.removeEventListener('ended', next); // helps for garbage removal I guess
      rotate(iterator.next())
    };
    if (done) { console.log('done!'); return };
    var current = orderMap[value];
    console.log('current: ', current);
    current.play();
    current.addEventListener('ended', next) // listen to 'ended' on audio, start next one
  }
  
  rotate(iterator.next()); // first call
}
```

Comment: How can I reset it to cal it again with a new order?

Comment: @RadekJohn you can incapsulate this logic into a function, where you pass 'order' array as an argument. Look at my edited code: call  `rotateAudio(order)` passing an array with numbers. When you need a different order - just call it with a different array.

Comment: Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @RadekJohn consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Done :-) Sorry I am new to this site.

Answer (score 2):

use [`onended`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp) event to play the next song, something like this:

```
var musics = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'];
var order = [2,1,3,4];
var player; //get your audio tag here
player.autoplay = true;

function playNext() {
    var current = order.shift();
    player.src = musics[current];
}

player.addEventListener('ended', playNext);
playNext();
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

use .onended instead .addEventListener, It is so reliable.

```
var musics = ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'];
var playArray=function(){
  if(order[]!=null){
    var voice =musics[0];
     voice.play();
    order.shift();
    voice.onended = function () {
         playArray();
    };
  }
}
```